# Wcf sharing variables between calls

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-6

**I have a wcf web service which i want to share information between calls** (diferent clients calls) .

**for example** sharing a dictionary between client calls. the dictionary can be change through calls (add/remove item etc) but i cant efford it to be deleted or to be renew for each call (it should be like a static database) .

is there any way to implement this issue?

allready tried a few suggestions but nothing realy seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx) defined outside of your service class - you would need to handle the very likely possibility that multiple calls will be accessing / modifying  the info at the same time so will need to lock the data maybe with a [ReaderWriteLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A nicer way of doing it, assuming you are using .net 4.0, would be to use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which contains built-in thread safety. If you are pre .net 4.0, there is a cache object in the System.Web namespace [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it was a bit of a pain having to add reference to system.web if you wanted to use it when writing windows apps so the MemoryCache implementation in .net 4.0 was a welcome addition.

Comment: Singletone indeed what im  looking for, memorycache sound more then an option. im looking to turn a dictionary into a shared object between calls. is there any more options available ?